# Laravel Pivot Table, Get Room belonging to users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The structure of my pivot table is

**room_id** - **user_id**

I have 2 users that exist in the same room.

How can I get the rooms they both have in common?

It would be nice to create a static class to have something like this.

```php
Room::commonToUsers([1, 5]);
```

Potentially I could check more users so the logic must not restrict to a certain number of users.

```php
Room::commonToUsers([1, 5, 6, 33, ...]);
```

Comment: do you want to search the user who has the same room?

Comment: I don't know what the room is, I want to find the room that is common to the users.

Comment: I want to get common room_id between two users?

Comment: you can try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Laravel project and make `users`, 'rooms', 'room_users' tables and their models
and defined a static function in `RoomUser` Model as below :

```
public static function commonToUsers($ids)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT room_id FROM room_users WHERE user_id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ') GROUP BY room_id HAVING COUNT(*) = ' . count($ids);
    $roomsIds = DB::select($sql);
    $roomsIds = array_map(function ($item){
        return $item->room_id;
    }, $roomsIds);
    return Room::whereIn('id', $roomsIds)->get();
}
```

in this method, I use self join that the table is joined with itself, `A` and `B` are different table aliases for the same table, then I applied the `where` condition between these two tables (A and B) and work for me.

I hope be useful.

Comment: This is the only working solution thank you. However, this restricts it to just 2 users, sorry for not making my question clear but if I wanted to do `Room::commonToUsers([1, 4, 5])` it's not dynamic

Comment: @itsliamoco I dynamic the query and tested it, work for me, I edited my answer, please try now, I hope useful

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the names of your relations, but I guess you can do like this :

```
$usersIds = [1, 5];
$rooms = Room::whereHas('users', function($query) use ($usersIds) {
      foreach ($usersIds as $userId) {
          $query->where('users.id', $userId);
      }
})->get();
```

It should work. `whereHas` allows you to query your relation. If you need to have a static method, you can add a method in your model.

Comment: This brings back rooms that user 1 and user 5 belong to. But I want only rooms they are both in.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more efficient way but laravel collection does have an `intersect` method. You could create a static function that retrieves and loop through each object and only retain all intersecting rooms. something like this

```
public static function commonToUsers($userArr){
  $users = User::whereIn('id',$userArr)->get();
  $rooms = null;

  foreach($users as $user){
    if($rooms === null){
      $rooms = $user->rooms;
    }else{
      $rooms = $rooms->intersect($user->rooms);
    }
  }

  return $rooms;
}
```

This code is untested but it should work.

Comment: made a small edit.. wrote down the wrong comparison operator..

Answer (score 0):

`Room` has many `users`, `user` has many `rooms`, so you can find the `room` which have those two `users`.

If your pivot table's name is `room_users`, then you can easily get the common room like this:

```php
public static function commonToUsers($user_ids) {
    $room = new Room();
    foreach($user_ids as $user_id) {
        $room->whereHas('users', function($query) use ($user_id) {
            $query->where('room_users.user_id', $user_id);
        });
    }
    return $room->get();
}
```

This code will convert to raw sql:

```sql
select * 
from `rooms` 
where exists (
    select * from `rooms` inner join `room_users` on `rooms`.`id` = `room_users`.`room_id` where `rooms`.`id` = `room_users`.`room_id` and `room_users`.`user_id` = 1
) 
and exists 
(
    select * from `rooms` inner join `room_users` on `rooms`.`id` = `room_users`.`room_id` where `rooms`.`id` = `room_users`.`room_id` and `room_users`.`user_id` = 5
)
```

Comment: This is basically reposting @Vincent Decaux pre-edited answer which the OP have already said did not work. Also very unlikely OP has `room_user` relationship for it to be used in your whereIn.

Comment: @Helioarch no, it's not, check this is from the pivot, and Decaux's anwser will convert query to where('user_id', 1)->where('user_id', 5), it will return empty result.

Comment: Vincent had `$query->whereIn('users.id', $usersIds);` before he edited his answer after OP commented that it did not work, since it return all room that belongs to any one of the user id in the array?. Isn't your code using the exact same concept?

Comment: @Helioarch ok, I have not seen the code before he edit.

Comment: @Helioarch I have fix my answer.

Comment: I've reverted the -1 since it's not a duplicate answer anymore, but i still don't think the OP would have a `room_user` relationship as it's not as laravel's many-to-many standard practise. I might be wrong about that though.

Comment: @Helioarch because the question is the rooms that users(1, 5) both have, that means user can have 1+ rooms, one room can have 2+ users. And he has pivot table with `user_id` and `room_id`, the `room_user` just the pivot name I assuming.

Comment: You are right. I just tried your `$query->where('room_user.user_id', $user_id);` on my own code and it ran. Sorry, in my own project i don't usually query the pivot's field so i usually do `where('users.id',$user_id)` instead and assumed that 'users' is actually the relationship name just like in pluck() method.